# Angularjs encoded values in the address bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following in my controller that is suppose to load a page

```
$scope.testing = function () {
        $window.location.href = "#/iCharges/";
    };
```

The route and everything is wroking fine. The only problem is when this loads the page the url in the browser shows up as

```
http://localhost:60482/main/loc#%2iCharges%2F
```

Problem is that instead of url showing #/iCharges/ It is replacing it with #%2iCharges%2F

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you should navigate to views in Angular:

```
$scope.testing = function () {
    $location.path('/iCharges');
};
```